# What is the locus defined by these equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, locus

I would like to know what is the locus of $x \in \Bbb R_+^n$ ($n=2$ would already be fine) defined by

$\sum a_i \cdot x_i$ s.t. $a_i+\epsilon \geq 0$, $\epsilon \in \Bbb R$.

I know that if $\epsilon =0$, it's the conical hull (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_combination#Conical_hull) for details) of the data points, but I'd like to generalize to $\epsilon >0$ and  $\epsilon <0$

I would also like to get the same in the "convex" case (i.e. when adding the constraint $\sum a_i = 1$). As you can notice, assume that the data $x$ are positive.

Thank you

Comment: But I am also interested in the case where $\sum a_i =1$

Comment: @JeanMarie *conical (sorry not native English speaker). I corrected the typo

Comment: @JeanMarie edited with a link

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1369799

Comment: if ε>0, say for example =1, it looks to be the initial cone augmented by a kind of little polygon around the origin.

Comment: @JeanMarie And I guess that if $\epsilon <=0$, it's the cone minus a polygon near the origin. However, I just tested it with 2 points, is that true for more ? How to extend this in the case of sum-to-one assumption for the $a_i$'s ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's make the question a little more precise.  We fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\varepsilon>0$, and define
$$\mathcal{A}_{n,\varepsilon}:=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty\left\{\sum_{i=1}^ka_ix_i:x_i\in(0,\infty)^n\;\&\;a_i\geq -\varepsilon\;\forall i\right\}$$
and
$$\mathcal{B}_{n,\varepsilon}:=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty\left\{\sum_{i=1}^ka_ix_i:x_i\in(0,\infty)^n\;\&\;a_i\geq -\varepsilon\;\forall i,\;\sum_{i=1}^ka_i=1\right\}.$$
Now we wish to characterize these sets in simpler terms.

If $\varepsilon<0$ then clearly
$$\mathcal{A}_{n,\varepsilon}=\mathcal{B}_{n,\varepsilon}=(0,\infty)^n$$
and if $\varepsilon=0$ then
$$\mathcal{A}_{n,0}=[0,\infty)^n$$
and
$$\mathcal{B}_{n,0}=(0,\infty)^n.$$

The case $\varepsilon>0$ is harder to see, and so for the sake of simplicity we work with $n=2$.  Let $x=(x(1),x(2))\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and set $c=|x(1)|\vee|x(2)|$. Then
$$-\varepsilon\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{c}x(i)=:a_i.$$
We can choose $y_2(1)>0$ small enough so that
$$y_1(1):=\frac{c}{\varepsilon }-\frac{x(2)y_2(1)}{x(1)}>0$$
Then we can choose $y_1(2)>0$ small enough so that
$$y_2(2):=\frac{c}{\varepsilon}-\frac{x(1)y_1(2)}{x(2)}>0$$
This yields
$$\frac{\varepsilon}{c}[x(1)y_1(i)+x(2)y_2(i)]=x(i),\;\;\;i=1,2$$
and hence
$$a_1y_1+a_2y_2=x,\;\;\;y_i\in\mathbb{R}_+^2,\;\;\;a_i\geq -\varepsilon.$$
It follows that
$$\mathcal{A}_{2,\varepsilon}=\mathbb{R}^2.$$

The computations will be harder, but it *should* be relatively routine to show that $\mathcal{A}_{n,\varepsilon}=\mathbb{R}^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Working with the convexity condition changes things.  Consider when $n=1$.  Then $\mathcal{B}_{1,\varepsilon}=\mathbb{R}$ when $\varepsilon>0$.  Indeed, if $x>0$ then $1\cdot x=x$ does the trick.  If $x\leq 0$ then we set $y=\frac{x-1-\varepsilon}{-\varepsilon}>0$ so that $-\varepsilon y+(1+\varepsilon)\cdot 1=x$.

I'll have to get back to you on $\mathcal{B}_{n,\varepsilon}$ when $\varepsilon>0$ for general $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, the thing is I suppose to know the $k$ points $x_i$. So I guess the union is not necessary